# Remove item from array of object with md-select and ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-ng-change

Im trying to remove the current selected item from my md-select. i played around with it and still didn't got it. i think i don't fully understand the way ng-value works in md-select. 
it dose not delete the selected item and also add the name property of the selected array to the first place in the list.

html

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl"  ng-app="MyApp">

     <div layout="column">
               <div layout="row">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;margin-top: 7px;">remove selected email:</span>

                <md-select 
                    data-ng-model="defaultEmailListItem.email"
                    aria-label="remove_email_md-select"
                    ng-change="itemChoosen()"       
                    style="margin:0px 5px;width:155px;">
                    <md-option
                        ng-repeat="item in emailList "
                        ng-value="item.name"
                        ng-bind="item.email">                   
                    </md-option>          
                </md-select>
       </div>
              <md-button 
                style="line-height:0px;width:66px;max-width:66px;min-width:66px;"
                class="md-raised " 
                aria-label="remove_email_md_button"
                ng-click="removeUserFromEmaillist()"
                ga-track-event="['email', 'choose', 'remove']"
                >remove 
            </md-button>
  </div>      


</div>
```

js

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.emailList=[
{name:"aaa",email:"aaa@gmail.com"},{name:"bbb",email:"bbb@gmail.com"},{name:"ccc",email:"ccc@gmail.com"},{name:"ddd",email:"ddd@gmail.com"},                 {name:"hhh",email:"hhh@gmail.com"}];


 $scope.defaultEmailListItem = $scope.emailList[0];

$scope.itemChoosen = function(){
  return $scope.defaultEmailListItem;
}

  $scope.removeUserFromEmaillist = function(){

    $scope.emailList = _.filter($scope.emailList),function(item){
     if(item.email !== $scope.defaultEmailListItem.email){
        return item ;
        }  
      };
    };



});
```

here is a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VemGzZ?editors=101#0
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyGJwe?editors=101)

Issues:

1. `ng-value="item.email"` instead of `item.name`.
2. `_.filter(Array, callback)`. You had not supplied the *callback* function, instead you had just declared a function, after closing the parenthesis!